# Orientation change with Auto Layout in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

How can I constrain a view such that it is centered when in portrait, but moves to one side of the screen when in landscape? I basically have one view above another in portrait, but want them to go side-by-side when the orientation changes. I don't want to have to create two different layouts for each orientation, and I'd like to stay in interface builder if possible.

For clarity I've created the following scrawling:

[image]

I'd like to be able to rotate between these layouts.

Comment: Put them in a stack view and change the axis based on orientation

Comment: I'm targeting iOS 7, so I'm unable to use stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

To achieve what you want you will have to play with size class. Use of size class from ios 9 onwards is different from from ios 7 & 8. So if you are targetting ios 7 then follow above link but in case of iOS 9 same can be acheived using StackView.